# "Три журнала собралось" or "собрались"?

Tags: грамматика

How would I say "3 journals were gathered"

- три журнала собрались?

or

- три журнала собралось?

More specifically, do i decline according to три or журнала?

If I'm wrong, how should i make the sentence?

Comment: sentences are capitalized. Please, don't ignore this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because someone did the gathering, you need to use impersonal sentences:

> Собрали три журнала.
>
> Было собрано три журнала.

You would use “собрались” where the subjects actually performed the action: Школьники собрались в классе; and “собралось” where, on the contrary, it just happened: В фильтре собралось много мусора.

As for declension, you decline “три журнала” as a whole. Трёх журналов, трём журналам etc.

Comment: Also, "[в подборку] собраны три журнала".

Answer (score 1):

Its' the *passive voice* here, so It can't be *собралось/собрались*, which is usually (if not always) about *people* who gathered. Literally, it's **Было собрано 3 журнала**. Depending on context it could also be **Забрали три журнала** (где-то приготовленные). However, **to gather** could be used here as a printing industry term:

> **Gather** – To assemble folded signatures in proper sequence.

https://www.pimw.org/about-us/the-printing-industry/glossary-of-print-terms/

which corresponds to the Russian term **подбирать** (отпечатанные) **листы**.

http://www.apostrof.ru/pubs/2620.html

So it could actually mean fulfillment of an intermediate operation in printing for 3 items in work:

> Произведён подбор листов для трёх журналов.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use собрались,because that presupposes animate nouns, people, but you can use собралось for things in impersonal sentence

> У меня **собралось** целых три журнала.(accumulated).

One of the meanings of the verb is

> **Насчитываться, доходить до какого-либо количества, числа**.

The declension of the noun depends on the numeral три. 
Another variant is passive voice which has already been covered in the previous answers. Both **было собрано** and **были собраны** are valid.